# Conditional query that displays on Woo product attribute pages

Tags: loop, query, conditional-tags

I have a custom query set up that currently modifies the product category pages of my website. I would also want this code to affect the product attribute archive pages of my website, but I am having trouble with the conditional statements.

Here is the conditional statement I am using now that modifies my product category pages:

```
function display_custom( $query ) {
if(!is_admin() && (in_array ( $query->get('post_type'), array('product') ) || $query->get('product_cat') != '') )
    {

CUSTOM QUERY GOES HERE

}
    return $query;
}
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'display_custom',800);
```

I tried just using `if (!is_admin())` but it didn't work.

Any pointers to make this query work on the product attribute pages?